# When I attempt to build this program I get this error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c++, division

I'm working on a homework problem for C++ and when I attempt to set this variable equal to the result of dividing these 2 numbers,and build the program I get the lvalue required as left operand of assignment error. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double width = 0.0;
    double height = 0.0;
    double area = 0.0;
    double paintneeded = 0;

    cout << "Enter the width of the wall in feet: ";
    cin >> width;

    cout << "Enter the height of the wall in feet: ";
    cin >> height;

    area = height * width;
    cout << "Total area to paint in square feet: " << area << endl;

    1000 / 500  = paintneeded;

    cout << "The amount of paint needed is :" << paintneeded << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assignments are `variable_to_assing_to = expression_to_get_the_value`. The order of the left- and right-hand sides are fixed.

Comment: The error message should have told you which line has the error. With that information, you could have come up with a much shorter [mcve] -- remove everything in the `main` function except the line with the error and the declaration of `paintneeded` (since that variable is used in the line with the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 / 500 is an rvalue.

Simply put, an rvalue is a temporary value that doesn't have a name that you can refer to later.
paintneeded is an lvalue, and this is what you should be assigning to:

```
paintneeded = 1000 / 500;
```

Although I suspect it would involve the area in the formula too :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, you are right.  paintneeded is an lvalue, and 1000 / 500 is an rvalue.  Was not quite with it yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

For this error change this line

`1000 / 500  = paintneeded;`

to

`paintneeded = 1000 / 500;`

Since your program doesn't have complete logic. You need to write logic like:
Paint per square area unit 'X' (some value).

For example: define a constant as shown below

`PAINT_PER_AREA  =  2;`

And then, 
`paintneeded = PAINT_PER_AREA * area;`

Comment: This won't work because the `area` needs to be involved.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It solves the error the OP is asking about. It won't lead to the expected result being printed, but that's another issue.